# How could I use the jQuery :contains() selector within a defined element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I want to use the jQuery :contains() selector, but only select elements within a specific  element. I'm not exactly sure how to go about it. For better understanding, I want to do something like this:

```
document.getElementById("main").$("div:contains("Hello World!")");
```

or

```
var a = document.getElementById("main");
$("a:contains("Hello World!")");
```

Except something that actually works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would first get the `main` element, then use jquery's `find` method to search only within it's child elements.  Something like this:

```
$("#main").find("div:contains(\"Hello World!\")");
```

Jquery doc: https://api.jquery.com/find/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily this way.

```
$('#main div:contains("Hello World!")')
```

or

```
$('#main').find('div:contains("Hello World!")');
```

or

```
$('div:contains("Hello World!")','#main')
```

In this case, the first parameter ( 'div:contains("Hello World!")' ) is the child of second parameter ( '#main' )